Wagtail Django migration doesn't get applied when running `migrate`
When I run Django makemigrations on Wagtail I get a migration (pasted at the bottom) which doesn’t seem to migrate properly. Here you see me making the migration successfully, applying it without errors and then, after doing runserver, being told that I have migrations to run.
(.venv)  development  ➜ app  manpy makemigrations
/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/utils/widgets.py:10: RemovedInWagtail70Warning: The usage of `WidgetWithScript` hook is deprecated. Use external scripts instead.
  warn(
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'freetag_chooser' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'pagetag_chooser' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'sectiontag_chooser' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace
Migrations for 'core':
  modules/core/migrations/0019_whofundsyoupage_stream.py
    - Add field stream to whofundsyoupage
(.venv)  development  ➜ app  manpy migrate
/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/utils/widgets.py:10: RemovedInWagtail70Warning: The usage of `WidgetWithScript` hook is deprecated. Use external scripts instead.
  warn(
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'freetag_chooser' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'pagetag_chooser' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'sectiontag_chooser' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, core, csp, django_cron, donations, importers, sessions, submissions, taggit, taxonomy, users, wagtail_localize, wagtailadmin, wagtailcore, wagtaildocs, wagtailembeds, wagtailforms, wagtailimages, wagtailredirects, wagtailsearch, wagtailsearchpromotions, wagtailusers
Running migrations:
  Applying core.0019_whofundsyoupage_stream...⏎
(.venv)  development  ➜ app  runserver
/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/utils/widgets.py:10: RemovedInWagtail70Warning: The usage of `WidgetWithScript` hook is deprecated. Use external scripts instead.
  warn(
/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/utils/widgets.py:10: RemovedInWagtail70Warning: The usage of `WidgetWithScript` hook is deprecated. Use external scripts instead.
  warn(
Performing system checks...

System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'freetag_chooser' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'pagetag_chooser' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'sectiontag_chooser' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace

System check identified 3 issues (0 silenced).

You have 1 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): core.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
May 14, 2024 - 16:33:16
Django version 5.0.4, using settings 'config.settings.development'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:5000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

And here is the code of the migration that's been made and doesn't seem to be being applied:
modules/core/migrations/0019_whofundsyoupage_stream.py
# Generated by Django 5.0.4 on 2024-05-14 16:31

import modules.core.blocks.override
import wagtail.blocks
import wagtail.fields
import wagtail.images.blocks
from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('core', '0018_auto_20240226_1608'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='whofundsyoupage',
            name='stream',
            field=wagtail.fields.StreamField([('rich_text', wagtail.blocks.StructBlock([('text', modules.core.blocks.override.RichTextBlock(label='Body text', required=True))], group=' Content')), ('image', wagtail.blocks.StructBlock([('image', wagtail.images.blocks.ImageChooserBlock(required=True)), ('alt_text', wagtail.blocks.CharBlock(label='Override image alt-text', required=False)), ('caption', wagtail.blocks.RichTextBlock(features=['link', 'document-link'], label='Override caption', required=False)), ('credit', wagtail.blocks.RichTextBlock(features=['link', 'document-link'], label='Override credit', required=False)), ('image_display', wagtail.blocks.ChoiceBlock(choices=[('full', 'Full'), ('long', 'Long'), ('medium', 'Medium'), ('small-image', 'Small')]))], group=' Content')), ('html_advanced', wagtail.blocks.StructBlock([('html', wagtail.blocks.RawHTMLBlock(label='HTML code', required=True)), ('styling', wagtail.blocks.ChoiceBlock(choices=[('default', 'Default'), ('remove-styles', 'Remove style')]))], group=' Content'))], blank=True, verbose_name='Additional content'),
        ),
    ]


Django thinks there are unapplied migrations, but in reality, the migration has already been applied. First of all you should use manage.py showmigrations to make sure this isn't the case.
If the migration is applied but Django "disagrees", use --fake. You may want to reapply the migration afterwards.

This is helpful thanks - I now start the server and don't get the issue. When you say reapply the migration afterwards, do you mean running migrate without using --fake?

@KindOfGuy yes, --fake only simulates moving on the migration dependency chain without actually executing any database changes.

If I run migrate --fake Django thinks I've run the migrations, so when I run it without the fake flag, nothing gets migrated. So is there any point in doing that second step? And how do I ACTUALLY apply the migrations?

Yes, it's still a problem because I can't seem to apply other migrations, and so get errors like Exception Value: column core_utilitypage.show_navigation_bar does not exist LINE 1: ...tilitypage"."body2", "core_utilitypage"."footer", "core_util... (I'm now trying to add a field called show_navigation_barit to theutilityPage`)
